# Jupyter notebook kernel error due to file not found /run/user/*/jupyter

Tags: linux, fedora, jupyter-notebook

I run a jupyter 4.4.0 notebook service (jupyter notebook --no-browser --port 8889) on a fedora 27 server, which I access remotely via a browser. After a few hours of using the service without any issues, I get a 'Kernel error'. Within the first few hours, I am able to start new notebooks without errors. However after a certain time I get the error message given below. It clearly tells me that the kernel error is due to missing file '/run/user/1001/jupyter/kernel-869f88b2-0895-40fb-b759-c518a1686484.json'.

On further investigation, I noticed that the file is missing because the entire jupyter directory is missing from /run/user/1001. The jupyter directory seems to get created when I first start the service and then appears to be getting automatically deleted after some time.

Days of searching has indicated that the issue is likely a result of inactivity, which causes either the OS or jupyter service to delete the /run/user/1001/jupyter directory.

So far I have not been able to figure out exactly what is deleting the /run/user/1001/jupyter directory or how to stop that from happening. Do you know how this could be resolved?

**Error Message**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1469, in _execute
    result = yield result
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1015, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 237, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_exc_info
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1021, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/handlers.py", line 73, in post
    type=mtype))
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1015, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 237, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_exc_info
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1021, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py", line 79, in create_session
    kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1015, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 237, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_exc_info
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1021, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py", line 92, in start_kernel_for_session
    self.kernel_manager.start_kernel(path=kernel_path, kernel_name=kernel_name)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1015, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 237, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_exc_info
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 285, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/services/kernels/kernelmanager.py", line 160, in start_kernel
    super(MappingKernelManager, self).start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_client/multikernelmanager.py", line 110, in start_kernel
    km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_client/manager.py", line 240, in start_kernel
    self.write_connection_file()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_client/connect.py", line 472, in write_connection_file
    kernel_name=self.kernel_name
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_client/connect.py", line 137, in write_connection_file
    with open(fname, 'w') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/run/user/1001/jupyter/kernel-869f88b2-0895-40fb-b759-c518a1686484.json'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I fix this problem by setting JUPYTER_RUNTIME_DIR variable. Jupyter stores runtime files in $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/jupyter by default. Setting JUPYTER_RUNTIME_DIR will override this behaviour. You can set it to some directory that won't be automatically cleaned up to prevent this error.

This is what i do before you start jupyter:

```
export JUPYTER_RUNTIME_DIR="path_to_my_home_directory/.jupyter_runtime"
```

And the problem is resolved!

Some more details that i find:

https://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/projects/jupyter-directories.html#envvar-JUPYTER_RUNTIME_DIR

https://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html#variables